# Calculate the area of a polygon on the surface of the Earth

Tags: polygon, area, wgs84, cartesian

I'm trying to write a function that will accept an array of coordinates and calculate the area of the polygon.

```
function getArea(lat_long: Array<LAT_LONG>){

  lat_long.push(lat_long[0])
  const n = lat_long.length

  const cart = lat_long.map((point) => convertToCartesian(point));

  let sum1 = 0;
  let sum2 = 0;
  
  cart.map((point, i, cart) => {
    if(cart[i + 1]) {
      const {X: lat1, Y: long1} = point;
      const {X: lat2, Y: long2} = cart[i + 1]
      sum1 += <number>lat1 * <number>long2
    sum2 += <number>long1 * <number>lat2
   }
  })
  return Math.abs(sum1 -sum2) / 2;
}
```

I'm using the shoelace algorithm to successfully calculate the area of the polygon. I convert the lat/long coordinates into their Cartesian formats before running the algorithm.

Input of an array of coordinates:

```
[
     -30.755695508016164,139.58931179712357,
    -31.026745675780326,139.67720242212357,
    -30.929020409557967,139.9243948049360,
    -30.563139898321857,140.02052517602982,
    -30.500447229869152,139.79530544946732,
    ])
```

Convert the above to Cartesian:

```
const convertToCartesian = ({ lat, long }: LAT_LONG) => {
  const { a, feSq } = WGS84;

  const sinLat = Math.sin(convertRad(<number>lat));
  const sinLong = Math.sin(convertRad(<number>long));
  const cosLat = Math.cos(convertRad(<number>lat));
  const cosLong = Math.cos(convertRad(<number>long));

  const h = 0;
  const v = a / Math.sqrt(1 - feSq * sinLat * sinLat);

  const X = (v + h) * cosLat * cosLong;
  const Y = (v + h) * cosLat * sinLong;
  const Z = (v * (1 - feSq) + h) * sinLat;

  return { X, Y, Z };
};
```

Output:

```
[
      {
        X: -4177052.98836046,
        Y: 3556294.7743405653,
        Z: -3242647.5585449743
      },
      {
        X: -4170740.6233994444,
        Y: 3539899.576439874,
        Z: -3268435.3161851424
      },
      {
        X: -4190241.3515973534,
        Y: 3525463.391770664,
        Z: -3259145.5543680554
      },
      {
        X: -4212041.526141104,
        Y: 3531751.3820798383,
        Z: -3224283.8117593047
      },
      {
        X: -4200822.826425785,
        Y: 3550559.9915549974,
        Z: -3218297.530026407
      },
      {
        X: -4177052.98836046,
        Y: 3556294.7743405653,
        Z: -3242647.5585449743
      }
    ]
```

Results in 774321690.7109375 from my function.
I've compared this to the result from https://www.mathopenref.com/coordpolygonareacalc.html which outputs: 774321690.7119141.

However, when I compare this to a tool such as Google Maps it is incorrect (1513405095.71 m² is the answer). I should be applying the spherical properties of the earth to get an accurate answer but I'm not sure how. I've tried `S = [θ - (n - 2)π]R²` where `θ` is the sum of the angles, `n` is the number of corners.

Comment: There are an infinite number of potential Cartesian equivalents for any lat/lon location, the easiest of which would be horrifically wrong for area calculation. You'll need to provide *how* you converted and what the conversion was before we could help.

Comment: Thanks. I've edited the post to include the input and output from converting to cartesian coordinates.

Comment: Where did you get the formula? What is the projection's name?

Comment: I got the formula from other developers who implemented such a conversion function. I'd like to use the Mercator projection. Do you have any suggestions for a formula I might use to calculate the surface area of a group of coordinates? thanks

Comment: The *last* thing you want to use for area calculation is Mercator -- it is consistently, progressively worse after you go north or south of the Equator

Comment: Your "convert to cartesian" function is converting to **3D Earth-centred Cartesian coordinates**. Then your area calc is dropping Z and computing the area of the polygon formed by the points projected onto the plane through the equator! Did you not understand what the code the "other developers" gave you was meant to do?